# Solid Mechanics FEM Simulation with Different Material Properties

Tags: finite-element-method, eigenvalues, solidmechanics

How would I assign different material properties to the "bar" and "support"? Meaning, for example, the bar would be assigned the properties of single-crystal Copper and the support single-crystal Nickel.

**Update:** More specifically,  `"MaterialModel" -> "LinearElasticAnisotropic"` is needed. The `If` statement works for properties like `"MassDensity"`, but I've been unsuccessful with the compliance matrix.

**Update 2:** Thanks to User21 comment about `IF` statement usage, the compliance matrix now has `IF` statements at every entry, and it runs. The issue now is that the reported frequencies are as if the solid part is not constrained in space. It's constrained the same way as a monolithic material which gives appropriate values. Any thoughts?

**Update 3:** It was a units (1*^-12) error that caused very low frequencies that made me think it was a constraint issue. Fixed in the code below (answer) and it seems correct.

**Update 4:** Runs significantly slower compared to the monolithic material, even with a coarse mesh. Any suggestions to speed it up would be appreciated. Please comment if a bounty would motivate anyone to take the code from my "answer" and speed it up for the first 60 Eigenmodes.

Comment: There is a section called 'Coupled heat transfer equation' in the solid mechanics monograph that shows how to do this.

Comment: @user21 can more than one compliance matrix be selected based on position? `"ComplianceMatrix"->If[Abs[y] <= 1, matA, matB]` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The If statement needs to be inside the matrix, at the individual entries level.

Comment: I know traditional way how to assign different material properties without modern upgrade like "ComplianceMatrix".

Comment: @user21 I was able to update the matrix to have `IF` at every entry, and it runs, however, the reported frequencies are as if it's not constrained. It's constrained the same way as a monolithic material which gives appropriate values. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Young, hm. Not sure what causes that. If you can post the complete code I can have a look tomorrow and try to figure it out.

Comment: As I understand we can't use `If[ ]` directly with FEM since it can't be compiled properly. It is why we use `Simplify`PWToUnitStep[PiecewiseExpand[#]] &` in 2D, but it is not working in 3D.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks for looking at this. `pars = <|"Material" -> {{y^2 < (barY/2)^2, Entity["Element", "Copper"]}, {y^2 > (barY/2)^2, Entity["Element", "Nickel"]}}|>;` works for isotropic simulations, but I need anisotropic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**

I recommend using `Piecewise` and added an example and an explanation below.

This is probably something that should be shown in the documentation and I'll add this. Here is how to do it. The compliance matrix needs to be given as a matrix. So using paradigms like `If[predicate, matA, matB]` do not work. The trick is to use the `If` (or even better Piecewise) statement inside the matrix at each entry. Here, however, we have to be careful that the entries are evaluated to numbers such that the evaluation can work efficiently. What we do not want is an entry like `If[predicate, matA[[1,1]], matB[[1,1]]]` In this case the evaluator will will have to look up the matrix values for each integration point. This is very inefficient. What we want is something like `If[predicate, valueA11, valueB11]` where the values are actual numbers. We use the compliance matrices for two materials:

```
matSNickel = {{5.00, -1.55, -1.55, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00}, {-1.55, 
    5.00, -1.55, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00}, {-1.55, -1.55, 5.00, 0.00, 0.00, 
    0.00}, {0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 13.10, 0.00, 0.00}, {0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 
    0.00, 13.10, 0.00}, {0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 13.10}};
matSCopper = {{7.69, -2.62, -2.62, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00}, {-2.62, 
    7.69, -2.62, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00}, {-2.62, -2.62, 7.69, 0.00, 0.00, 
    0.00}, {0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 20.62, 0.00, 0.00}, {0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 
    0.00, 20.62, 0.00}, {0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 20.62}};
```

Here is how we can then set up a single compliance matrix based on an `If` statement that uses a predicate where each of the components are active:

```
cmat = MapThread[
   If[Abs[y] <= Abs[barY/2], #1, #2] &, {matSNickel, 
     matSCopper}*1*^-12, 2];

pars = <|"MaterialModel" -> "LinearElasticAnisotropic", 
   "MassDensity" -> If[Abs[y] <= Abs[barY/2], 8960, 8908], 
   "ComplianceMatrix" -> cmat|>;
```

Note that for example

```
cmat[[1, 1]]

(* If[Abs[y] <= 0.0015, 5.*10^-12, 7.69*10^-12] *)
```

This is very efficient. An even better approach is to use `Piecewise`, because `Piecewise` does not have the `HoldRest` attribute the `If` statement has. For this reason the expressions in the branch will automatically be evaluated. So the recommended expression to use is \

```
cmat = MapThread[
   Piecewise[{{#1, Abs[y] <= Abs[barY/2]}}, #2] &, {matSNickel, 
     matSCopper}*1*^-12, 2];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion (+1). It is nor clear how to define matrix like `matSNickel` and `matSCopper` in general case?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Did you want to say "not" or "now"?

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear how  to define matrix like matSNickel and matSCopper in general case?

Comment: OK, @AlexTrounev, I have updated the answer a bit. Let me know if this is clearer now.

Comment: Thank you @user21 (+1)!

Comment: I have added a small update and recommend using `Piecewise` in stead of `If`.

Answer (score 5):

This is answer for the first question about titanium and nickel usage in one installation, and for the last question about how to speed up evaluation. First step is a mesh generation and visualization with FEM

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

barX = 0.0100;
barY = 0.0015;
barZ = 0.1000;

supportX = 0.0750;
supportY = 0.0050;
supportZ = 0.0010;

barSolid = 
  Cuboid[{-(barX/2), -(barY/2), -(barZ/2)}, {(barX/2), (barY/
      2), (barZ/2)}];
supportASolid = 
  Cuboid[{-(supportX/2), -supportY - (barY/2), -(supportZ/
       2)}, {(supportX/2), -(barY/2), (supportZ/2)}];
supportBSolid = 
  Cuboid[{-(supportX/2), (barY/2), -(supportZ/2)}, {(supportX/
      2), (barY/2) + supportY, (supportZ/2)}];
reg = RegionUnion[barSolid, supportASolid, supportBSolid];


mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, "MeshOrder" -> 1, MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-6];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

Second step is material property definition

```
en1 = Entity["Element", "Titanium"];

en2 = Entity["Element", "Nickel"];

param1 = 
 QuantityMagnitude[
  en1[{"YoungModulus", "PoissonRatio", "MassDensity"}]]

param2 = 
 QuantityMagnitude[
  en2[{"YoungModulus", "PoissonRatio", "MassDensity"}]]
```

Please pay attention that `en1, en2` have mixed bases so that if we evaluate for example `en1` then we have

```
en1[{"YoungModulus", "PoissonRatio", "MassDensity"}]

Out[]= {Quantity[116., "Gigapascals"], 0.32, 
 Quantity[4.507, ("Grams")/("Centimeters")^3]}
```

For frequencies simulation we need Young modulus in Pa, while mass density in $kg/m^3$.Therefore we define parameters in different regions as follows

```
 cons = (-barX/2 <= x <= barX/2 && -barY/2 <= y <= 
    barY/2 && -barZ/2 <= z <= barZ/2); Y = 
 With[{Y1 = 10^9 param1[[1]], Y2 = 10^9 param2[[1]]}, 
  If[cons, Y1, Y2]]; \[Nu] = 
 With[{n1 = param1[[2]], n2 = param2[[2]]}, 
  If[cons, n1, n2]]; \[Rho] = 
 With[{r1 = 10^3 param1[[3]], r2 = 10^3 param2[[3]]}, 
  If[cons, r1, r2]];
```

Here we use `With` since we can't use `If` directly with FEM due to compilation problem. Last step

```
tvars = {{u[t, x, y, z], v[t, x, y, z], w[t, x, y, z]}, 
   t, {x, y, z}};
constraintA = 
  DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y, z] == 0, v[t, x, y, z] == 0, 
    w[t, x, y, z] == 
     0}, (x^2 <= (barX/2)^2 && y^2 == (barY/2)^2 && 
      z^2 <= (supportZ/2)^2) || (x^2 >= (supportX/2)^2 && 
      y^2 >= (barY/2)^2 && z^2 <= (supportZ/2)^2)];
op = SolidMechanicsPDEComponent[{{u[t, x, y, z], v[t, x, y, z], 
     w[t, x, y, z]}, t, {x, y, z}}, 
   Join[<|"YoungModulus" -> Y, "PoissonRatio" -> \[Nu], 
     "MassDensity" -> \[Rho]|>]];

{evals, evecs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{op == {0, 0, 0}, constraintA}, tvars[[1]], 
   t, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 6];
 Re[Sqrt[evals]/(2 Pi)]

(*Out[]= {9.90091, 9.90091, 10.1875, 10.1875, 16.6058, 16.6058}*)
```

Visualization of first and fifth modes

```
{DensityPlot3D[evecs[[1, 1]], {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", OpacityFunction -> None, Boxed -> False,
   Axes -> False, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "Titanium-Nickel"], 
 DensityPlot3D[evecs[[5, 1]], {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", OpacityFunction -> None, Boxed -> False,
   Axes -> False, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "Titanium-Nickel"]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

**Update 1.** The answer for the second question about copper-nickel installation:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

barX = 0.0100;
barY = 0.0030;
barZ = 0.1000;

supportX = 0.06000;
supportY = 0.00150;
supportZ = 0.00100;

barSolid = 
  Cuboid[{-(barX/2), -(barY/2), -(barZ/2)}, {(barX/2), (barY/
      2), (barZ/2)}];
supportASolid = 
  Cuboid[{-(supportX/2), -supportY - (barY/2), -(supportZ/
       2)}, {(supportX/2), -(barY/2), (supportZ/2)}];
supportBSolid = 
  Cuboid[{-(supportX/2), (barY/2), -(supportZ/2)}, {(supportX/
      2), (barY/2) + supportY, (supportZ/2)}];

solid = RegionUnion[barSolid, supportASolid, supportBSolid];

mesh = ToElementMesh[solid, "MeshOrder" -> 1, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Volume" -> 5*^-10}, MeshQualityGoal -> 1, 
  "MeshElementType" -> "HexahedronElement"]

en1 = Entity["Element", "Copper"];

en2 = Entity["Element", "Nickel"]; 
 
param1 = 
 QuantityMagnitude[
  en1[{"YoungModulus", "PoissonRatio", "MassDensity", "ShearModulus"}]]

param2 = 
 QuantityMagnitude[
  en2[{"YoungModulus", "PoissonRatio", "MassDensity", "ShearModulus"}]]

cons = (-barX/2 <= x <= barX/2 && -barY/2 <= y <= barY/2 && -barZ/2 <=
     z <= barZ/2); Y1 = 
 With[{y1 = 10^9 param1[[1]], y2 = 10^9 param2[[1]]}, 
  If[cons, y1, y2]]; G1 = 
 With[{g1 = 10^9 param1[[4]], g2 = 10^9 param2[[4]]}, 
  If[cons, g1, g2]]; \[Nu]1 = 
 With[{n1 = param1[[2]], n2 = param2[[2]]}, 
  If[cons, n1, n2]]; \[Rho]1 = 
 With[{r1 = 10^3 param1[[3]], r2 = 10^3 param2[[3]]}, 
  If[cons, r1, r2]];
param1 = 
 QuantityMagnitude[
  en1[{"YoungModulus", "PoissonRatio", "MassDensity", "ShearModulus"}]]

param2 = 
 QuantityMagnitude[
  en2[{"YoungModulus", "PoissonRatio", "MassDensity", "ShearModulus"}]]

cons = (-barX/2 <= x <= barX/2 && -barY/2 <= y <= barY/2 && -barZ/2 <=
     z <= barZ/2); Y1 = 
 With[{y1 = 10^9 param1[[1]], y2 = 10^9 param2[[1]]}, 
  If[cons, y1, y2]]; G1 = 
 With[{g1 = 10^9 param1[[4]], g2 = 10^9 param2[[4]]}, 
  If[cons, g1, g2]]; \[Nu]1 = 
 With[{n1 = param1[[2]], n2 = param2[[2]]}, 
  If[cons, n1, n2]]; \[Rho]1 = 
 With[{r1 = 10^3 param1[[3]], r2 = 10^3 param2[[3]]}, 
  If[cons, r1, r2]];
(*compliance matrix in general case*)
D0 = {{1/Subscript[Y, x*x], -(Subscript[\[Nu], y*x]/Subscript[Y, y*y]), -(Subscript[\[Nu], z*x]/Subscript[Y, z*z]), 0, 0, 0}, 
    {-(Subscript[\[Nu], x*y]/Subscript[Y, x*x]), 1/Subscript[Y, y*y], -(Subscript[\[Nu], z*y]/Subscript[Y, z*z]), 0, 0, 0}, 
    {-(Subscript[\[Nu], x*z]/Subscript[Y, x*x]), -(Subscript[\[Nu], y*z]/Subscript[Y, y*y]), 1/Subscript[Y, z*z], 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 1/Subscript[G, y*z], 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1/Subscript[G, x*z], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/Subscript[G, x*y]}}; Compliance matrix in this case
mat = D0 /. {Subscript[Y, x*x] -> Y1, Subscript[Y, y*y] -> Y1, 
    Subscript[Y, z*z] -> Y1, Subscript[\[Nu], y*x] -> \[Nu]1, 
    Subscript[\[Nu], z*x] -> \[Nu]1, Subscript[\[Nu], x*y] -> \[Nu]1, 
    Subscript[\[Nu], z*y] -> \[Nu]1, Subscript[\[Nu], x*z] -> \[Nu]1, 
    Subscript[\[Nu], y*z] -> \[Nu]1, Subscript[G, y*z] -> G1, 
    Subscript[G, x*z] -> G1, Subscript[G, x*y] -> G1};
```

Compliance matrix test

```
mat /. {x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 0}

(*Out[]= {{7.69*10^-12, -2.6*10^-12, -2.6*10^-12, 0, 0, 
  0}, {-2.6*10^-12, 7.69*10^-12, -2.6*10^-12, 0, 0, 
  0}, {-2.6*10^-12, -2.6*10^-12, 7.69*10^-12, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
  2.1*10^-11, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 2.1*10^-11, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  2.1*10^-11}}*)

mat /. {x -> 0, y -> (barY/2) + supportY/2, z -> 0}

(*Out[]= {{5.0*10^-12, -1.6*10^-12, -1.6*10^-12, 0, 0, 
  0}, {-1.6*10^-12, 5.0*10^-12, -1.6*10^-12, 0, 0, 
  0}, {-1.6*10^-12, -1.6*10^-12, 5.0*10^-12, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
  1.3*10^-11, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1.3*10^-11, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  1.3*10^-11}}*)
```

Eigen system computation

```
tvars = {{u[t, x, y, z], v[t, x, y, z], w[t, x, y, z]}, t, {x, y, z}};

pars = <|"MaterialModel" -> "LinearElasticAnisotropic", 
   "MassDensity" -> \[Rho]1, "ComplianceMatrix" -> mat|>;

eigenmodeOperator = 
  SolidMechanicsPDEComponent[tvars, 
   Join[pars, <|"AnalysisType" -> "Eigenmode"|>]];

constraintB = 
  SolidFixedCondition[
   x^2 >= (supportX/2)^2 && y^2 >= (barY/2)^2 && 
    z^2 <= (supportZ/2)^2, tvars, pars];

{evals, evecs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{eigenmodeOperator == {0, 0, 0}, constraintB}, 
   tvars[[1]], t, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 6];

eigenfrequencies = Re[Sqrt[evals]/(2 Pi)]

(*Out[]= {155.855, 319.74, 513.075, 551.638, 1642.23, 2346.6}*)
```

Visualization

```
 {DensityPlot3D[
  evecs[[1, 1]] // Re // Evaluate, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", OpacityFunction -> None, Boxed -> False,
   Axes -> False, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "Copper-Nickel"], 
 DensityPlot3D[
  evecs[[5, 1]] // Re // Evaluate, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", OpacityFunction -> None, Boxed -> False,
   Axes -> False, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "Copper-Nickel"]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thank you for the answer (+1)! The compliance matrix for multiple materials seems to be a tough nut to crack for fast simulation.

Comment: I advice against using `Activate` on PDE models that are solved with FEM, because it can lead to wrong results as explained in this very similar example [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#1585211872).

Comment: @Young Did you use the linear elastic orthotropic compliance matrix D with shear modulus G in your answer?

Comment: @user21 Thank you. Your are right. Code has been updated.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I used `"MaterialModel" -> "LinearElasticAnisotropic"`

Answer (score 3):

With the help of user21, the following code simulates the Eigenmodes of a solid component with two different densities and compliance matrices based on position within the mesh.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

barX = 0.0100;
barY = 0.0030;
barZ = 0.1000;

supportX = 0.06000;
supportY = 0.00150;
supportZ = 0.00100;

barSolid = 
  Cuboid[{-(barX/2), -(barY/2), -(barZ/2)}, {(barX/2), (barY/
      2), (barZ/2)}];
supportASolid = 
  Cuboid[{-(supportX/2), -(barY/2), -(supportZ/2)}, {(supportX/
      2), -supportY - (barY/2), (supportZ/2)}];
supportBSolid = 
  Cuboid[{-(supportX/2), (barY/2), -(supportZ/2)}, {(supportX/
      2), (barY/2) + supportY, (supportZ/2)}];

solid = RegionUnion[barSolid, supportASolid, supportBSolid];

mesh = ToElementMesh[solid, "MeshOrder" -> 1, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Volume" -> 5*^-10}, MeshQualityGoal -> 1, 
  "MeshElementType" -> "HexahedronElement"]

matSNickel = {
   {5.00, -1.55, -1.55, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00},
   {-1.55, 5.00, -1.55, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00},
   {-1.55, -1.55, 5.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00},
   {0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 13.10, 0.00, 0.00},
   {0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 13.10, 0.00},
   {0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 13.10}};
matSCopper = {
   {7.69, -2.62, -2.62, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00},
   {-2.62, 7.69, -2.62, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00},
   {-2.62, -2.62, 7.69, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00},
   {0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 20.62, 0.00, 0.00},
   {0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 20.62, 0.00},
   {0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 20.62}};

matSMulti[loc_] := {
  {If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[1, 1]], 
    matSNickel[[1, 1]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[1, 2]], 
    matSNickel[[1, 2]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[1, 3]], 
    matSNickel[[1, 3]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[1, 4]], 
    matSNickel[[1, 4]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[1, 5]], 
    matSNickel[[1, 5]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[1, 6]], 
    matSNickel[[1, 6]]]},
  {If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[2, 1]], 
    matSNickel[[2, 1]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[2, 2]], 
    matSNickel[[2, 2]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[2, 3]], 
    matSNickel[[2, 3]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[2, 4]], 
    matSNickel[[2, 4]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[2, 5]], 
    matSNickel[[2, 5]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[2, 6]], 
    matSNickel[[2, 6]]]},
  {If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[3, 1]], 
    matSNickel[[3, 1]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[3, 2]], 
    matSNickel[[3, 2]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[3, 3]], 
    matSNickel[[3, 3]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[3, 4]], 
    matSNickel[[3, 4]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[3, 5]], 
    matSNickel[[3, 5]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[3, 6]], 
    matSNickel[[3, 6]]]},
  {If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[4, 1]], 
    matSNickel[[4, 1]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[4, 2]], 
    matSNickel[[4, 2]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[4, 3]], 
    matSNickel[[4, 3]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[4, 4]], 
    matSNickel[[4, 4]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[4, 5]], 
    matSNickel[[4, 5]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[4, 6]], 
    matSNickel[[4, 6]]]},
  {If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[5, 1]], 
    matSNickel[[5, 1]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[5, 2]], 
    matSNickel[[5, 2]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[5, 3]], 
    matSNickel[[5, 3]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[5, 4]], 
    matSNickel[[5, 4]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[5, 5]], 
    matSNickel[[5, 5]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[5, 6]], 
    matSNickel[[5, 6]]]},
  {If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[6, 1]], 
    matSNickel[[6, 1]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[6, 2]], 
    matSNickel[[6, 2]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[6, 3]], 
    matSNickel[[6, 3]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[6, 4]], 
    matSNickel[[6, 4]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[6, 5]], 
    matSNickel[[6, 5]]], 
   If[Abs[loc] <= Abs[barY/2], matSCopper[[6, 6]], matSNickel[[6, 6]]]}
  }

tvars = {{u[t, x, y, z], v[t, x, y, z], w[t, x, y, z]}, t, {x, y, z}};

pars = <|
   "MaterialModel" -> "LinearElasticAnisotropic",
   "MassDensity" -> If[Abs[y] <= Abs[barY/2], 8960, 8908],
   "ComplianceMatrix" -> matSMulti[y]*1*^-12
   |>;

eigenmodeOperator = 
  SolidMechanicsPDEComponent[tvars, 
   Join[pars, <|"AnalysisType" -> "Eigenmode"|>]];

constraintB = 
  SolidFixedCondition[
   x^2 >= (supportX/2)^2 && y^2 >= (barY/2)^2 && 
    z^2 <= (supportZ/2)^2, tvars, pars];

{evals, evecs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{eigenmodeOperator == {0, 0, 0}, constraintB}, 
   tvars[[1]], t, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 6];

eigenfrequencies = Re[Sqrt[evals]/(2 Pi)]
```

Comment: It is a nice attempt (+1). Nevertheless, please see my answer.

Comment: Did you use the linear elastic orthotropic compliance matrix D with shear modulus G in your answer?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I used "MaterialModel" -> "LinearElasticAnisotropic"

Comment: Thank you. I finally compute test with  linear elastic orthotropic compliance matrix D with shear modulus G in general case. See Update 1 to my answer.